# use priorvalue function

Tags: picklist, validation-rule

if opportunity type(this is Picklist) is base or solutions
and stagename(this is also picklist) change Order Pending to Lost

then I want error message from validation rule is you cannot manually change stage order pending to lost when opportunity type is base or solutions.

i tried this but not working

```
AND(
  ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName ,"Order Pending")),
  OR(ISPICKVAL( Type , "Base"),ISPICKVAL(Type, "Solutions"))
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If opportunity type(this is Picklist) is base or solutions and stagename(this is also picklist) change Order Pending to Lost

```
AND(
  ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName) ,"Order Pending"),
  ISPICKVAL(StageName,"Lost"),
  OR(ISPICKVAL( Type , "Base"),ISPICKVAL(Type, "Solutions"))
)
```

Comment: @cloudZigZag cool